# Power BI interactive dashboard

Tags: encoding, report, visualization, powerbi-desktop, dashboard

How can I select specific interactive dashboards from whole power bi file and share them with my manager
I have to create report from power bi and a create many dashboards at one file but I want to select only two pages or two dashboard and share them with mt manager